# How to get curl option with string

Tags: php, curl

I am working with PHP 5.3 and Curl.

I want to make my curl calls more flexible so one function can handle all my calls. The problem I am having is with the curl option.

It uses values like CURLOPT_POST to represent a LONG value.

To make my function more flexible, I want to set these options with defaults, and change them based on a passed array.

ex;

```
function doCurl($options){
   $defaults = array('CURLOPT_POST' => true, 'CURLOPT_HEADER' => false);
   foreach($options AS $k=>$v) $defaults[$k] = $v;
   foreach($defaults AS $opt_k=>$v) curl_setopt($curl, $opt_k, $v)
```

}

So, how can I handle $opt_k so it can get the LONG value of the original variable?

Comment: Thanks, however, according to the docs you have to send 'An array specifying which options to set and their values. The keys should be valid curl_setopt() constants or their integer equivalents.'. So, the same issue. I need to convert the string keys to the 'integer equivalents'.

Comment: Have you tried to wrap that in a class, like `$curl = new Curl($options); echo $curl->exec()`?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that what you need is a function that converts strings into PHP constants. You can use the [constant function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php). Your code would end up like the following:

```
function doCurl($options){
   $defaults = array('CURLOPT_POST' => true, 'CURLOPT_HEADER' => false);
   foreach($options AS $k=>$v) $defaults[$k] = $v;
   foreach($defaults AS $opt_k=>$v) curl_setopt($curl, constant($opt_k), $v)
}
```

Comment: This is so simple and jet so usefull. It's a suprise this is not used more often when it comes to these kind of flags in php.

Answer (score 0):

```
function doCurl($options) {
   $defaults = array(CURLOPT_POST => true, CURLOPT_HEADER => false);
   curl_setopt_array($curl, !empty($options) ? ($options + $defaults) : $defaults);
}
```

Except for the fact that $curl variable is undefined in the scope of the function but you probably know how to deal with it.

If you want to convert string to constant value use something like:

```
function get_curlopt_from_string($str) {
    if (preg_match('/^CURLOPT_/', $key) && defined($str)) {
        return eval('return $str;');
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But your first answer sent me in the right direction for solving my problem. After looking at the function curl_setopt_array(), it occurred to me that I could just pass the the array with options array with the correct 'integer equivalents'.

Comment: oh..but in your first answer, you had '$options + $defaults', but that returned an error. At the time $options was empty. Is this the correct way to handle the 2 arrays so that defaults are overwritten by values set in $options?

Comment: curl_setopt_array($curl, !empty($options) ? ($options + $defaults) : $defaults);

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. However, it would not recognize the settings from the $options. So I just used an array_merge with $options as the second array. I realize this means it may set some items twice, but since it won't actually be used a lot, it is a small deficit.

Comment: Why are you using regular expressions to match a singular word? Why to `eval('return $str')` if you can simply return `$str?`

Answer (score 0):

Try this example it will help you to solve your problem

```
<?php

$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'var1' => 'some content',
        'var2' => 'doh'
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/submit.php', false, $context);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I really don't understand what it is you are doing. It looks like you may have pasted from the middle of some text.